# How many changes can you track in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Microsoft to take note and also to move toward a final version of a manuscript.

I am relying on the track change to not lose any note. So I would like to know how many changes will Microsoft Word keep track of?

So far I am working on a document still can see the changes in red and they are searchable. However, I wonder about the number of changes that will remain in the track change system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of changes that can be tracked is not mentioned in [Operating parameter limitations and specifications in Word](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/operating-parameter-limitation). As noted by @yoki in the comments, the changes are part of the document, as such they will be limited by the size of a file Word can open which is 512MB. So, as long as you have not reached the file size limit, the changes will be tracked.

The maximum number of comment is 2147483647.

**Word 2007 and later versions limits**

```
| Operating parameter                                            | Limit         |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|---------------|
| Maximum number of bookmarks                                    | 2,147,483,647 |
| (Style Definition) maximum number of styles                    | 4,079         |
| Maximum number of lists                                        | 2,047         |
| Maximum number of comments                                     | 2,147,483,647 |
| Maximum number of fields                                       | 2,147,483,647 |
| Number of subdocuments in a master document                    | 255           |
| Maximum number of moves                                        | 2,147,483,647 |
| (Range Permission) maximum number allowed                      | 2,147,483,647 |
| Size of file Word can open                                     | 512 MB        |
| Maximum number of records to display in recipients list dialog | 10000         |
```

Comment: The changes definitely *are* part of the document.

Comment: @yoki Thanks. I will edit in a moment.

Comment: Related to the point above, are all changes tracked or only the ones between savings?

Comment: @BND Don't take my word for it but I will presume that as long as the setting is on the changes will be tracked. They will only stop if the setting (track change) is off. Obviously, the document must be saved for the changes to also be saved.